# Vertically aligning multiple elements in piecewise equation using cases

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I have the following LaTeX code. It produced output aligned along the commas that divide the equations from their respective areas of validity, as shown below.

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        i_0-\sqrt{2\ln{2}}\sigma\leq i_k\leq i_0+2\sigma, & i_0>0\\
        i_0-3\sigma\leq i_k\leq i_0+\sqrt{2\ln{2}}\sigma, & i_0<0
    \end{cases},
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I would like to have the i_k vertically aligned as well as the commas. When I try to insert extra alignment markers I get a compilation error. Is there a simple way to have multiple points of vertical alignment in the cases environment, or is there a different environment that I can use for this purpose which would allow for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `alignedat`. I'll show a version with commas next to the formula and a version with aligned commas.

In general, I'd avoid commas hanging from nowhere, like the one you put after `cases`. If you want full punctuation, add commas after `i_0>0` and `i_0<0`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  i_0-\sqrt{2\ln 2}\,\sigma &\leq i_k &&\leq i_0+2\sigma,               &\qquad& i_0>0\\
  i_0-3\sigma               &\leq i_k &&\leq i_0+\sqrt{2\ln 2}\,\sigma, &\qquad& i_0<0
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  i_0-\sqrt{2\ln 2}\,\sigma &\leq i_k &&\leq i_0+2\sigma               &,\qquad& i_0>0\\
  i_0-3\sigma               &\leq i_k &&\leq i_0+\sqrt{2\ln 2}\,\sigma &,\qquad& i_0<0
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also introduced a couple of refinements.

1. `\log{2}` is wrong: try `\log{\sin{x}}` and `\log\sin x` to realize why.<sup>1</sup>
2. After a square root, a `\,` can help in better clarifying the meaning.

<sub><sup>1</sup> `\ln` is no different; it's just I can't bear that notation for the logarithm. `;-)`</sub>

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll take your advice about log notations as well ^_^

Comment: I actually don't see a difference between the two log examples you give: https://latexbase.com/d/d46e3243-13a6-46fc-8881-f089a20a505b

Comment: @KBriggs Sorry, wrong example.